# Is the graph described below bipartite?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, bipartite-graphs

Let $G$ be a graph in which:

1. Every vertex is represented as binary sequence having the length $k$. The number of vertices in such graph is $n=2^k$.
2. Vertices are connected only when corresponding binary sequences differ on $j$ positions, where $j$ is odd number.

Is such graph bipartite? If so, prove it.

I tried to color vertices using BFS and I would say that is is bipartite, however I don't have any ideas how to prove it. Also sorry for any spelling mistakes I made, English is not my primary language.

Answer (score 2):

The parities of the vertices incident to any edge in $G$ must be opposite, since $j$ is odd. Let all vertices whose bitstring has even parity receive one colour and all those whose bitstring has odd parity receive another; this gives a valid 2-colouring of $G$, proving its bipartiteness.

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand. What is a parity of vertices?

Comment: @PhilipMoreira The parity of the binary sequence associated with the vertex.